# Car is rigged, jagged, or pixelated

Tags: modeling, mesh, import

Car is rigged, jagged, or pixelated, need help on how to fix

[image]

Comment: What are the dimensions of the car and which distances are set for _Clip Start_ and _End_ in the sidepanel under _View_?

Comment: Please share the file: https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform and share the link